# How to extract only year from created_at column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime

Querying the database for the `created_at` value gives the following output:

```
>> kevin.created_at
=> Sun, 21 Aug 2016 07:46:26 UTC +00:00
```

How can I extract only the year from this information? 
I tried to treat `kevin.created_at` as a string and see if I could get what I want with:

```
>> kevin.created_at.split[3].to_i
```

However I get this message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for Sun, 21 Aug 2016 07:46:26 UTC +00:00:Time
```

Therefore I tried with:

```
>> kevin.created_at.to_a
=> [26, 46, 7, 21, 8, 2016, 0, 234, false, "UTC"]
```

So I may have a solution with:

```
>> kevin.created_at.to_a[5]
=> 2016
```

Is there any better or more elegant solution to query Postgresql for this information?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use .year function from ruby Time class as:

```
kevin.created_at.year
```

Answer (score 5):

In Postgres, the `EXTRACT` function can get you just the year from a date:

```
# SELECT EXTRACT('year' FROM created_at) as year FROM USERS LIMIT 1;
 year
------
 2016
(1 row)
```

In Ruby, if you already have your record on hand, you can just use the `Time#year` method:

```
user.created_at.year  # => 2016
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternately you can use `date_part` function

```
SELECT DATE_PART('year' , created_at) AS year FROM USERS
```

please refer [datetime function in postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html)

hope it helps.